# Difference between 2 ways of passing data to Flutter route

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm reviewing the flutter.dev tutorials.  I'm a bit confused by 2 of their articles.

1) Send data to a new screen
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

2) Pass arguments to a named route
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

To me, they more or less both accomplish the same thing but in different ways.   It seems #1 passes the data using Navigator's "arguments" parameter and then pulls it out in the target widget via ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments.  It seems #2 uses the target widget's constructor to receive the data.  Am I missing something?  When would I use one vs the other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two main differences:

- push vs pushNamed, which means dynamic vs static routes.
- Who creates the `Route` subclass. Using `push`, it's the widget that calls `Navigator.push` whereas using `pushNamed`, it's `MaterialApp`/`CupertinoApp` or `onGenerateRoute`.

This has an impact on features such as transitions between routes, separation of concern, or deep links.

Comment: ahhhh!  you are right!  the tutorial goes from a push() example, then gives 2 examples with pushNamed(), then it goes back to a final example using push() but doesn't make it obvious and/or call out the differences between the two methods.  good catch, makes perfect sense now!  i still need to learn the trade-offs between dynamic -vs- static (named) as you stated, but I can investigate that myself.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, you are saying _"This has an impact on features such as transitions between routes, separation of concern, or deep links."_, could you elaborate or share a documentation/article about that, please?